# How to recover a serialized byte-string

Tags: python

I have mistakenly seralized bytes to my database so it is saved as:

`b'content-from-the-database'`

That is how it looks in postgresql when I select the data through psql. I receive it in Python as a string with the b'' chars. Is there a way to convert this to a normal string? I have collected data for a long time and would like not to restart it.